# Terminology: are "accessible" and "inherited" synonymous

Tags: oop, inheritance, terminology

If a superclass' methods are accessible by a subclass is this exactly the same meaning as saying that the methods are inherited by a subclass?

Comment: It is definently not a synonym, as a class can have an inherited method, that is inaccessible to other classes (protected), and a class can have an accessible method that cannot be inherited (final...)

Answer (score 2):

You'll generally want to be careful using "accessible" and "inherited" interchangeably. Accessible is used if the subclass can access the methods at all, for example the methods are public or protected. Inherited is a different case; while a subclass will generally inherit all non-private methods from a superclass, if the method has the keyword `final` then the class will not be inherited by the subclass. Of course, terminology and keywords vary by programming language, but usually methods can be accessible by classes that aren't subclasses and not all accessible methods can be inherited.